# Error no queue in vhost on application startup

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to start a Spring Boot application which has RabbitMQ configured by this configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfig implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {

    public static final String AMQP_EXCHANGE_NAME = "test-queue";

    @Bean
    public Exchange accessExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(AMQP_EXCHANGE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(AMQP_EXCHANGE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2MessageConverter consumerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory() {
        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
        factory.setMessageConverter(consumerJackson2MessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory());
    }
```

But I'm getting the error `no queue 'test-queue' in vhost '/'`:

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'test-queue' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:509) ~[amqp-client-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:340) ~[amqp-client-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:162) ~[amqp-client-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:109) ~[amqp-client-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:643) ~[amqp-client-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:581) ~[amqp-client-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

This problem only occurs when I have the following listener defined:

```
    @Transactional
    @RabbitListener(queues = RabbitConfig.AMQP_EXCHANGE_NAME)
    public void doSomething(TestDTO dto) {
        ...
    }
```

It seems that I'm trying to consume from the queue, but the queue where not created. If I create the queue through the RabbitMQ Management interface, the error does not occurs.

Is there a way to automatically create this queue, so I do not get this error?

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your `Queue` bean. You also don't seem to have a `RabbitAdmin` in your configuration (required for auto declaration of queues, exchanges, bindings).

See [Configuring the Broker](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#broker-configuration).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
private AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin;

@Bean
public Binding binding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
    // automatically create this queue, so you do not get this error.
    amqpAdmin.declareQueue(queue); 
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(AMQP_EXCHANGE_NAME);
}
```